# How to create a form and connect it with a download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, email, download

I'm looking for hours now, how to create a simple form on a website and by submitting, start a download.

I want a simple form with name, last name, and email adress. This should be send to me via email. With submitting the name, it should either start a download of a file or if easier, i want to send an e-mail to the submitted email address with a download link in it.

Any idea on how to do that or do you know a tutorial i didn't find yet?

Thanks a lot!
Marc

Comment: I never done something in your case before, but may I know what kind of file that you want user to downloaded? Once I use rails to provide a report for user with `pdf` format also `xls` format, and if the user chose `xls` format, then the Excel will automatically downloaded. But that was a file with data from system. And how about your case?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know of framework that doing just so,

but it not to hard implement it yourself.

1. make anchor tag that redirect user to download.
2. bind the evnt of clicking that anchor using jquery `.on` function.
3. in the JS  function send an ajax with the serialised info. throw `.ajax` function.
4. when its complete, redirect user by using `location.assign('/dl.php?f=123.mp3');` built in JS function.

is that help? (if not, do not vote me down, just ask further and i help)

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyJS I forgot to add, that i just started with Ruby on Rails. So i create a form, and after submitting the information in the form i can redirect them by using location.assign...?

Comment: that true, although the user is not aware of the form he sent, because its in the background. so for the user: he clicked the button, then wait for a sec, then redirect for new tab that ask him weather to save the file or execute it.... that in theory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use send_file method of Ruby http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file 
to download a file after submitting a form
and if you want to send it as an email attachment to download you can use

attachments["attachment_name"] = path-of-your-attachemnt

and above attachment will go through your email.